# How can I set a a state variable from two UI elements?

Tags: javascript

So, apologies if this is too much of an open and beginner-like question.

I am trying to build a single page app, in which one can control a variable in two ways:

- by dragging the corresponding datapoint on a D3 scatterplot chart
- by setting its value with a slider

I would like the chart to update when the slider gets moved, and the slider to move when the chart is updated by dragging the data on the chart.

I have thought of handling this through:

- a spaghetti tangle of events
- a proxy object mediating the changes

However I'm asking myself (and the illustrious SO community) is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyword for solving this is 'data binding'. There are several frameworks out there, which are able to solve this. That means, that you have a javascript model, which holds the value, you want to work with and something like a proxy, which handles changes and stuff and applies the changes to the view or respectively to the mode..

In case you might need this more often, which usually applies to single page apps, I would recommend you to use some framework, which does the work for you instead of reinventing the wheel.

If you want to stay with client based Javascript, you might take a look into Angular.js (never used it, but maaaany people do and really do like it) or Knockout.js (I work with it, but there are no more further developments).

Within the last years and now many peoply switched to Node.js and Angular2 (a further development of Angular.js) or React.js or Vue.js. You might also take a look into it, but going into detail would blow up the answer. Moreover I only know some basics right now and other people can do better and already did better.